# Navigation Menu dropdown

Tags: css, navigation

i am having a problem which is small but frustrating:

look at the top menu on my site: www.integratedphysicaltherapy.ie

the "Sports Injury Management" link  seems to be a effected by its dropdown element in some way. Ive had a look but can't see whats causing it. Any help would be much appreciated.

here is the code

```
#header .header-links .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1111;
    border: 0px solid #303030;
    background: #1C1C1C;
}
#header .header-links .sub-menu a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #303030;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0px 0 10px;
}
#header .header-links .sub-menu li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
}
#header .header-links .sub-menu a:hover,
#header .header-links .sub-menu .current-menu-item a {
}

#pre-header .sub-menu li,
#header .sub-menu li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}
#header .sub-menu li {
    padding: 2px 1px;
}
#header .sub-menu li:hover {
    padding-left: 1px;
}

#header .menu > li > a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#header .menu > li.menu-hover > a,
#header .menu > li.current_page_item > a, 
#header .menu > li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#header .menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #F33F3F;
}
.main-navigation:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 100%;
}
.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}
#pre-header .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
#header .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: please be specific, what do you mean by "seems to be a effected by its dropdown element in some way"???

Comment: in which browser do you observe the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. I checked the link and the menu is working perfectly.